# Linq: return biggest value of several columns and column name

Tags: wpf, linq

I have a table in a WPF project which contains some string columns s1,s2,s3 and several numeric columns n1,n2,n3,n4.

In a LINQ query I need to select the row:

```
Dim query = From li in myList where li.s1="ok"
```

Now, I need to know those column which contains the biggest value out of n1,n2,n3,4. It means the result should be something like:

```
"The biggest value (4) is in column n2"
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

I found some "FindMax" result on Google but actually they never give the column name nor its column index...

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to normalize your data like this:

```
var norm = query.Select(q=>new { Column="n1", Value=q.n1 })
  .Concat(query.Select(q=>new { Column="n2", Value=q.n2 }))
  .Concat(query.Select(q=>new { Column="n3", Value=q.n3 }))
  .Concat(query.Select(q=>new { Column="n4", Value=q.n4 }));
```

Now you can easily find the largest value like this:

```
var largest = norm
  .OrderByDescending(n=>n.Value)
  .First();
```

And output:

```
Console.WriteLine($"The biggest value ({largest.Value}) is in column {largest.Column}.");
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work great if I select a single row. But if my `query` contains multiple rows, your code snippet

    `var largest = norm
  .OrderByDescending(n=>n.Value)
  .First();`

still only returns a simple anonymus type containing 1 column and 1 value entry). What I would need is to have a "largest value" result per row over all n1,n2,...,n10 of each row.

Comment: If you need it per row, then @mm8 has a good solution.  If you don't need to know which column it came from, then there are even easier solutions by just using Math.Max.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var items = list.Where(x => x.S1 == "ok")
    .Select(x => new[] {
                    new { PropertyName = nameof(x.N1), Value = x.N1 },
                    new { PropertyName = nameof(x.N2), Value = x.N2 },
                    new { PropertyName = nameof(x.N3), Value = x.N3 },
                    new { PropertyName = nameof(x.N4), Value = x.N4 }}
        .OrderByDescending(y => y.Value)
        .First())
    .ToList();

foreach(var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"The biggest value ({item.Value}) is in column {item.PropertyName}.");
}
```

**VB.NET Version:**

```
Dim items = List _
    .Where(Function(x) x.S1 = "ok") _
    .Select(Function(x) {New With
    {
        Key .PropertyName = NameOf(x.N1),
        Key .Value = x.N1
    }, New With {
        Key .PropertyName = NameOf(x.N2),
        Key .Value = x.N2
    }, New With {
        Key .PropertyName = NameOf(x.N3),
        Key .Value = x.N3
    }, New With {
        Key .PropertyName = NameOf(x.N4),
        Key .Value = x.N4
    }}.OrderByDescending(Function(y) y.Value).First()) _
.ToList()
```